# How to get javascript error messages inside OnClientClicking handler of a RadButton?

Tags: telerik, google-chrome-devtools, telerik-radbutton

I have a webpage with a RadButton, in the OnClientClicking handler, I have a scripting error. How can I have that error reported in the developer tool console?

The output when I run this page is that when I have clicked the button, I get an alert with the text "1", then an alert with the text "2" and then nothing else happens.

The expected outcome is that I get those two message boxes and then a console log in the following format:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: not_defined is not defined

aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestErrorOutputInRadButtonOnClientClickingHandler.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.TestErrorOutputInRadButtonOnClientClickingHandler" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test()
        {
            alert(1);
            alert(2);
            console.log(not_defined);
            alert(3);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"/>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="test" OnClientClicking="test"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [JavaScript Errors - Throw and Try to Catch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp). Also cancel the event to prevent postback, so that you can actually see the error message you caught.

```js
function test(sender, args) {
    args.set_cancel(true)
    try {
        console.log(not_defined);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```